# how to add two values in angular js data commng from get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

unable to add `{{ cost -- selling_price }}`  please suggest any one how to add two numbers  when whole data comes from get or post request (work on ajax data two add two numbers )

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('associate', []);
    app.controller('addassociate', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
        $http.get('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/user/addassociate_request')
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.data1 = response.data;
                angular.forEach($scope.data1, function (value, key) {
                    for (x in value) {
                        $('#planoutlook').append('<tr><td>' + value[x].plan_type + '</td><td>' + value[x].plan_name + '</td><td> <input  class="form-control" ng-model="cost"   value="' + value[x].cost + '"></td><td> <input  class="form-control" ng-model="cost"   value="' + value[x].selling_price + '"></td><td><div class="form-group discount-form-group"><input  class="form-control" ng-model="discount" name="plan[]" data-id="' + value[x].id + '" value="' + value[x].default_discount_percentage + '"></div></td><td>{{cost -- selling_price}}</td></tr>');
                    }
                });
            })
    }]);
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you using `$('#planoutlook').append()`? If you had used pure Angular you would not have faced the issue

Answer (score 0):

The angular approach avoids appending elements to the DOM.
You need an ng-repeat binded to an array. When you receive data from your async request you must add that data to your previously binded array. So ng-repeat can update the DOM for you and you will avoid binding problems

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically add an element using jQuery and expect that some angular inside would magically work. To create such HTML with angular dynamically, you need to *compile* the template (see `$compile`).

Now, for you problem, the logic itself is flawed. What you should do is using *ng-show* and *ng-repeat*. The idea is:

- define a `$scope.data1`
- in your view, use `ng-show="data1"` on your `table` to hide it when no data is available
- use `ng-repeat="data in data1"` to iterate in your data and create your rows
- upon receiving data, assign them to `$scope.data1`

Here is an example of HTML with `ng-show` and `ng-repeat` to create a table:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table ng-show="data1">
    <tr ng-repeat="data in data1">
      <td>{{data.one}}</td>
      <td>{{data.two}}</td>
      <td>{{data.one - data.two}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

In your callback, use:

```
$scope.data1  = data;
$scope.$apply(); // if the callback was not triggered by angular
```

This fiddle gives you an example: https://jsfiddle.net/qdtakovu/

Comment: you are welcome. Please, don't forget to mark the question as answered using the checkmark on the left.